# field is never assigned to and will always have default value nulls

Tags: c#, null

I'm getting this error sorry about all this i goofed i need to change the values and 
dont know how that is the quetion how do i change the values from null

> field is never assigned to and will always have default value nulls

In the following code, where indicated:

```
GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

//  this is ling gives me field is never assigned to and will alwayhave defult value nulls c#
Texture2D marioTexture;

int marioYPos=100;
int marioXPos=100;
int marioWidth=64;
int marioHeight=64;

// and this line give me field is never assigned to and will alwayhave defult value nulls c#
Texture2D PongBallFinalTexture;

int PongBallFinalYpos=50;
int PongBallFinalXpos=50;
int PongBallFinalWidth=32;
int PongBallFinalHeight=32;

graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear (Color.CornflowerBlue);

spriteBatch.Begin ();
spriteBatch.Draw (marioTexture, new Rectangle (marioXPos, marioYPos, marioWidth, marioHeight), Color.White);
base.Draw (gameTime);
spriteBatch.Draw (PongBallFinalTexture, new Rectangle (PongBallFinalXpos, PongBallFinalYpos, PongBallFinalWidth, PongBallFinalHeight), Color.White);
base.Draw (gameTime);

spriteBatch.End ();
```

Comment: And the question is ...?

Comment: You said you were new to the site... so start by educating yourself about valid questions [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: the question is how to i change it so that it dosent have a a value of null and jeff your link didnt work fyi

Comment: @user3762125 use `@` when replying directly to someone so they get notified. Also the link works fine for me should go here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in the code you posted, you never assign any value to those two fields giving the error, you only declare them. Using uninitialized variables is not allowed in C#. These two specifically always have null value because that's the default for variables of object types other than the basic language types described in [Default Values Table (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx).

To make it work, you need to assign the values, the same as you do with positions and sizes there. E.g. directly in declaration:

```
Texture2D marioTexture = new Texture2D(graphics.GraphicsDevice, marioWidth, marioHeight);
Texture2D PongBallFinalTexture = new Texture2D(graphics.GraphicsDevice, PongBallFinalWidth, PongBallFinalHeight);
```

or later in the program, separate from declaration, but before they are used:

```
Texture2D marioTexture;
Texture2D PongBallFinalTexture;
...
marioTexture = new Texture2D(graphics.GraphicsDevice, marioWidth, marioHeight);
PongBallFinalTexture = new Texture2D(graphics.GraphicsDevice, PongBallFinalWidth, PongBallFinalHeight);
```

using the [basic constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd231959.aspx). It's just an example, you have to know how you want to construct the textures, what to assign to them.

Comment: may i ask how i would change that ? as i said im only just starting out

Comment: i did what you suggested and am now getting "a feild initializer cannon reference the non-static feild,mmethod, or property

Comment: @user3762125 I see, that depends on your context. If these are class fields you cannot initialize in the declaration using the other class fields. You can initialize them later, in the constructor or other appropriate method call when all the fields are available, as in the second example.